# Laravel, Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, laravel

Hello I am having a problem with my ajax request in laravel, it returns this error

```
"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException"
```

and I guess the append is not working because the error is now showing. this is what I have in my app.

in my routes

```
Route::post('admin/email', array(
            'uses' => 'AdminController@email_submit',
            'as' => 'email_submit'
            ));
```

Controller

```
public function email_submit()
    {
            $validator = Validator::make(
                array('content' => Input::get('message')),
                array('content' => 'required|min:10')
            );

            if ($validator->fails()){
                return Response::json([
                    'success'=>false,
                    'error'=>$validator->errors()->toArray()
                    ]);
            }

            return Response::json(['success'=>true]);
}
```

In my views.

```
@section('errors')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="alert alert-info info" style="display:none;">
                    <ul>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@stop

@section('content')
<div>
    {{Form::open(array('method' => 'post'))}}
        {{Form::label('Subject')}}
        {{Form::text('subject', null , array(
        'placeholder' => 'Subject',
        'class' => 'form-control'
        ))}}<br>

        {{Form::label('Message')}}
        {{Form::textarea('message', null , array(
        'placeholder' => 'Write here..',
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'id' => 'message'
        ))}} 
        <br>

        {{Form::submit('Send Email', array(
        'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
        ))}}
    {{Form::close()}}
</div>
@stop

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var info = $('.info');

            $('form').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('message',$('#message').val());

                $.ajax({
                    url:'email',
                    method:'post',
                    processData:false,
                    contentType:false,
                    cache:false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: formData,
                    success:function(data){
                        info.hide().find('ul').empty();
                        if(!data.success){
                            $.each(data.errors,function(index, error){
                                info.find('ul').append('<li>'+error+'</li>');
                            });
                            info.slideDown();
                        }else{
                            info.find('ul').append('<li>ITS WORKING</li>');
                            info.slideDown();
                        }
                    },
                    error:function(){}

                });

            });

        });     
    </script>
```

I hope someone can help me understand why I'm getting this error and the append is not working. Thanks

Comment: At what url you are displaying the form with ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax url sends data to */email*, but your route is configured to */admin/email*. Pick one or the other. try

```
$.ajax({
  url:'/admin/email',
  ...
```

Comment: @seanarce try to add slash: `url:'/admin/email'`

Comment: @seanarce you have a different error this time. post that error.

Answer (score 0):

One of the many cool features in Laravel is the automatic CSRF security, so, when you try to access protected routes via AJAX you will get a TokenMismatchException error. So, in addition to what has been said by @kaspars, you would also want to...

Add a new meta tag in the head section of your layout

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Tell jQuery to pass the token along whenever an AJAX call is made.

```
$(function() {
   $.ajaxSetup({
       headers: {
           'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
      }
     });
  });
```

Tell Laravel that if the request was sent via AJAX to look for the token in the headers and throw an error if the specified token does not match.

```
Route::filter('csrf', function() {
    $token = Request::ajax() ? Request::header('X-CSRF-Token') : Input::get('_token');
    if (Session::token() != $token) throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
});
```

Read more at [Laravel 4 – CSRF Tokens When Using jQuery’s AJAX](http://words.weareloring.com/development/laravel/laravel-4-csrf-tokens-when-using-jquerys-ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

> "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException"

means that the url is incorrect the best way to echo urls in laravel is {{URL::to('email_submit')}} since you have named your route 'email_submit'. so the ajax code should be this :

$.ajax({

> url: " {{URL::to('email_submit')}} ",

!note that there should be quotes